# Redirect to another page with a 200 status code instead of 302 in SilverStripe 3.1

Tags: silverstripe

Is it possible to redirect to another page with a 200 status code instead of 302?

Here is my code:

```
class SpecialsHolderPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    // ...
    $this->redirect('otherSpecialPage/');  // gives a 302 status code
    // ...
}
```

I know it is possible to just make it a redirector page in the CMS, but I want the option of either content for this page type or a redirection. Or is there a method that would be more correct than a redirect here?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a second parameter, `$this->redirect('otherpage', 301);`, but giving it a status 200 would not make sense. You're redirecting, that's what the 300 series is for.

Comment: The [second parameter of the redirect function](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-SS_HTTPResponse.html#222)  will only accept values between [301 and 307](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-SS_HTTPResponse.html#59). If any other value is given the redirect code will default to `302`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so now the important question...is there a method that would be more correct than a redirect here?

Comment: @user3257693 You could just output the same contents, eg. use a `VirtualPage`. As soon as you're changing URL, using status 200 is not correct.